# calling a child class method in OnMouseDown() of sprite in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

Good Day all, I am trying to make a simple 2D game and here is how it works. Assume there is a sprite "tent", and whenever i clicked the tent, the console will print out a message. Sounds straightforward is it? However I'm like stuck in the middle of it and I know I am gonna facepalmed myself so hard after this. What I did in my script is:

```
public abstract class Player : MonoBehaviour {

protected string _name;
// Use this for initialization
public Player(string name)
{
    _name = name;
}

public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; }
}

void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}}
```

Next I have a child class called Civilian

```
public class Civilian : Player {

// Use this for initialization

public Civilian(string name):base(name)
{

}
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

}
Then in my script "Tentclicked", i want to called the function of sleep when the sprite is clicked.

```
public class tentclicked : MonoBehaviour {

void OnMouseDown()
{
   // c.Sleep();
}


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

}

And you are wondering what is c and what it is point to? I instantiated a new class in another script called testing1.

```
public class testing1 : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text p1name;
public void Awake()
{
    //p1name.text = "Hello";
    //Civilian C = Scriptss.AddComponent<Civilian>();
    //GameObject theCivilian = GameObject.Find("Scriptss");
    // Civilian c = theCivilian.GetComponent<Civilian>();
    //c.Name = Testingsavename.playernames.username;
    //c.Name = "Hello";


}

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    if (Choosechar.choice.choicecount == 1)
    {
        Civilian c = new Civilian(Testingsavename.playernames.username);
        p1name = GetComponent<Text>();
        p1name.text = c.Name;

    }
```

I have already add a circle collider to my sprite. The error is that in tentclicked, c does not exist in context. So i suspect it may be that unity does not know what c is. I am thinking of making civilian class a static one, and just called Civilian.civilian.Sleep() in tentclicked script....

Comment: Creating a MonoBehaviour is not done through constructor but AddComponent

Comment: @Everts Hi, Can you please elaborate more, I don't understand what you mean by not done through constructor, do you mean that i should not create a new civilian class by constructor and instead use add component?

Comment: Civilian is a Player which is a MonoBehaviour so the usual way is to attach the component to a game object with AddComponent

Comment: @hopeestheim if either of these answers helped you, we would be much obliged if you selected one as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"c" does not exist in this context because your `tentclicked` class has no reference to it. Find "c" with `GameObject.Find(string name)` and assign the gameobject value to a variable in `tentclicked`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, is it correct if i create a new game object and drag the 'Civilian' Script into the game object? 
And then in my 'tentclicked' script:

Comment: public GameObject c; Inside OnMouseDown()
c = GameObject.Find("Civilian");
c.Sleep();
    }

Comment: That's correct! MonoBehaviour scripts are placed onto GameObjects in the Hierarchy window of the editor. If you do not want to find the game object every time mouse click is detected, then get the reference to the game object before then and have it available to the class scope instead of just the method scope.

Comment: I am currently trying another method which I following at this post,https://answers.unity.com/questions/7555/how-do-i-call-a-function-in-another-gameobjects-sc.html, i can call the function in another script just fine, but it does not work when is use 'OnMouseDown' to call the function. Maybe you can enlighten me on why is that :)

Comment: Where is your code for Civilian.Sleep()? Is it Public in scope? Where are you calling it from that it works? Inside of Civilian?

Comment: just a simple Debug.Log("Hello") to test that it really executes the function, and yes it is public in scope. I call it from Update than it works just fine.

Comment: As long as you have the same reference in `Update` as you do in `OnMouseDown`, I see no reason why it would work in one and not the other

Comment: I am also troubled with this error, this is the error log message I am getting.                                                 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
tentclicked.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Scripts/tempetc/tentclicked.cs:11)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)          maybe the error rings a bell for you??

Comment: Find out which object is null, because that error can be really vague. It's not often the compiler will tell you exactly which object, but from where it was last called.

Comment: OMG, i forget to drag the gameobject that contain Civilian script into the sprite thus the error. Now it works! Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You could raycast from the current mouse position towards the object (just make sure that the object has a collider.

```
void OnMouseDown()
{

   RaycastHit hit; 
   Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
   if ( Physics.Raycast (ray,out hit,100.0f)) 
   {
      Civilian c = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Civilian>();
      c.Sleep();
   }
}
```